# File upload with Rails 4, Strong Parameters and Carrierwave

Tags: file-upload, carrierwave, nested-forms, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I am porting an application that uses Carrierwave to Rails 4, but I have problems with strong params. I have a model with

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
```

Here is how uploaded images are passed:

```
{
    # ...
    "model"=>
    {
        # ...
        "photos_attributes"=>
        {
            "1362752177921"=>
            {
                "image"=>"test.jpg",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I can't seem to figure out how to write parameters that will accept `photos_attributes`.

I have tried `.permit(photos_attributes: [])` but it simply skips them, when I use `permit!`, `uuid` that is created before saving doesn't appear in SQL and this is the second issue:

```
photos.uuid may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "photos" ("created_at", "model_id", "image", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Documentation for strong parameters is lacking here and I am not even sure how to proceed.

**Update** 
This worked with the nested attributes:

```
params.permit( ..., :photos_attributes => ['id', 'title', 'image', '_destroy'])
```

But looks like either Carrierwave or Nested Form should be updated for Rails 4 first. It simply tries to save an empty image all the time. Same code (without strong_params) works in Rails 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked with the nested attributes:

```
params.permit( ..., :photos_attributes => ['id', 'title', 'image', '_destroy'])
```

But looks like either Carrierwave or Nested Form should be updated for Rails 4 first. It simply tries to save an empty image all the time which I kinda eliminated with `:reject_if`, but still it is not 100 working.